# accessing ctypes returned object's methods

Tags: python, ctypes

I need to wrap c++ dll to python. I'm using `ctypes` module for that.

c++ header is something like:

```
class NativeObj
{
    void func();
}

extern "C"
{
    NativeObj* createNativeObj(); 

}; //extern "C"
```

I want to create `NativeObj` in python code and then call its `func` method.

I wrote this code and get pointer to `NativeObj` but I didn't find how to access `func`

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> d = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('dll/path')
>>> obj = d.createNativeObj()
>>> obj
36408838
>>> type(obj)
<type 'int'>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot call C++ instance methods from ctypes. You will need to export a non-member function that will call the method. It will look like this in C++:

```
void callFunc(NativeObj* obj)
{
    obj->func();
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
import ctypes
d = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('dll/path')
obj = d.createNativeObj()
d.callFunc(obj)
```

It would also be useful to tell `ctypes` about the types involved.

```
import ctypes
d = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('dll/path')

createNativeObj = d.createNativeObj
createNativeObj.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
callFunc = d.callFunc
callFunc.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]

obj = createNativeObj()
callFunc(obj)
```